# What does it mean for a linear algebraic group to act reductively

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

I was reading [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82828062.pdf) by Baues and on page 918 he mention that $S$ **acts reductively** on the cochain complex and on page 919 again he mention the word "**Since $T$ acts reductively on the complex...**". I have tried searching for the meaning of this everywhere but I could not find the usage of this word. Maybe because I am not an expert in linear algebraic group theory I dont know where to find it. Please help me I really need to know the meaning of this.

Moreover, if a linear algebraic group acts reductively on a cochain complex why does it acts trivially on the cohomology of that cochain complex?